# Chapterbib gives citation undefined and [?] when also using hyperref package, how to solve?

Tags: hyperref, undefined, chapterbib

I am using the packages `hyperref` and `chapterbib`. The citations kept showing as `[?]`, even though I could find the correct keys back in the `aux` and `bbl` files. After excluding packages one-by-one I found that when I remove `\usepackage{hyperref}` from my packages, I do get the correct reference.

Is there a way to use both of these packages at the same time? Am I missing something in the options of the package that I should add?

---

**Working example:**

In main directory, `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book} 
% comment out \usepackage{hyperref} to get [1] instead of [?]
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{chapterbib} 
\begin{document}
\include{chapters/chapter1}
\end{document}
```

in `chapters/` directory, `chapter1.tex`:

```
\chapter[Example]{Test}
test: \cite{albertRoleRegulatoryVariation2015}
\bibliographystyle{naturemag}
\bibliography{chapters/chapter1}
```

in `chapters/` directory, `chapter1.bib`:

```
@article{albertRoleRegulatoryVariation2015,
  title = {The Role of Regulatory Variation in Complex Traits and Disease},
  author = {Albert, Frank W. and Kruglyak, Leonid},
  year = {2015},
  month = apr,
  volume = {16},
  pages = {197--212},
  issn = {1471-0064},
  doi = {10.1038/nrg3891},
  journal = {Nature Reviews Genetics},
}
```

Build with `pdflatex main.tex; bibtex chapters/chapter1; pdflatex main.tex; pdflatex main.tex`

Comment: Have you tried to run bibtex inside the `chapters` folder? (just as a test)

Comment: After your comment I have tried this, but it gives the same result ([?] when including hyperref, [1] when removing hyperref)

Comment: Sigh, first rule of `hyperref`: `hyperref` should be loaded last, Second rule of `hyperref` there are a few exceptions to the first rule, `chapterbib` is not one of them. Compiles just fine if I change the order of `chapterbib` and  `hyperref`

Comment: I was not aware of this rule. Switching hyperref to the bottom indeed fixes the problem. Can you put this as answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With very few exceptions the `hyperref` package has to be the last of the packages loaded (as it needs to patch several packages)

In this case loading `hyperref` after `chapterbib` solves the problem